# Client-Server application: can't connect to java server from android mobile phone

Tags: java, android, client-server

I am trying to connect to java (server) from android phone (client).
Server code:

```
import java.net.*;

/**
* Created by mwalko on 07.06.16.
*/
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    try
    {
        ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket (8601);
        for (;;)
        {
            Socket newsock = sock.accept();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I can talk with it by cURL:

```
curl localhost:8601
Hello :: enter QUIT to exit 

From server: GET / HTTP/1.1. 

From server: Host: localhost:8601. 

From server: User-Agent: curl/7.47.0. 

From server: Accept: */*. 

From server: .
```

But when I try to connect from android which works on this code (I also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to AndroidManifest.xml):

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.102", 6000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

I get an error:

```
06-07 20:09:03.530 7319-7319/com.example.root.client E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.root.client, PID: 7319
                                                                   06-07 21:45:20.990 25482-25520/com.example.root.client W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.102 (port 6000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I can ping 192.168.1.101 from phone. Why can't I connect to server, are there any bugs?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message in the debug console, it states.

> failed to connect to /192.168.1.102 (port 6000): connect failed:
>   ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Your Server code has a socket for port 8601, which means it is expecting requests at that port, not 6000. Change your android request port to 8601, or server listening port to 6000.

You also state that you can ping **192.168.1.101**, but in the java client you are creating a connection to IP **192.168.1.102**. For example, if server code was running on **192.168.1.101**, then every request from the android client (192.168.1.102 in this case) should be forwarded to **192.168.1.101**, through port 8601, usually written as: **192.168.1.101:8601**

Comment: Yes, that's true what you wrote but it's editing issue. I tried both port (6000 and 8601) to listen and connect, I mean I got port 6000 in client and 6000 on server then changed both to 8601. I'm sure there is problem with blocked ports or something on router. Good post anyway!
PS I pinged 192.168.1.102 (computer ip), my mistake